# Showing 2 text boxes when button click JS

Tags: javascript, html, buttonclick

I have implemented a coding to show a text-box when the user clicks a button. I need to modify that coding to view 2 text-boxes when user clicks that same button. I'll put the coding down below. Thanks!

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-9">
  <div id="welcomeDiv"  class="answer_list" style="display:none;">  <input type="text" /></div>

  <input type="button" name="answer" value="Customize Size" onclick="showDiv()" />

</div>
```

```
function showDiv(){
      $( "#welcomeDiv" ).show( "slow" );
}
```

Comment: This isn't PHP, it's javascript. Anyway, the solution is to change your div id to a class and assign that class to both divs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one .

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#input1").hide();
             $("#input2").hide();
        $("#hide").click(function(){
            $("#input1").hide();
             $("#input2").hide();
        });
        $("#show").click(function(){
            $("#input1").show();
             $("#input2").show();
        });
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <input type="text" id="input1"/>
    <input type="text" id="input2"/>

    <button id="hide">Hide</button>
    <button id="show">Show</button>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Hope this help :)

Answer (score 0):

this is exactly same like your code check this out
this is [fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/j8xwxa3t/5/)
and with code snippet also

```
 <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-9">
  <div id="welcomeDiv"  class="answer_list">  <input type="text" /></div>
  <input type="button" name="answer" value="Customize Size" />
</div>
```

this is javascript little bit different but you will get it

```
$("input[type='button']").click(function(){
      $("#welcomeDiv").show('slow');
});
```

i dont like to give style in elements so use css.css

```
#welcomeDiv{
  display:none;
}
```

```js
$("input[type='button']").click(function(){
      $("#welcomeDiv").show('slow');
});
```

```css
#welcomeDiv{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-9">
  <div id="welcomeDiv"  class="answer_list">  <input type="text" /></div>
  <input type="button" name="answer" value="Customize Size" />

</div>
```

Comment: Maybe you need click to hide so let me know i will try to help you